# resample a time series of a dataframe and use previous value for variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe, variables, time-series, resampling

I want to combine two dataframes with different time stamps. The data is from two different signals with a different frequency. The data frames look like this

```
df1 = data.frame(time = c(0.12, 0.21, 0.33, 0.42), 
             var1 = c(1, NA, 4, 6),
             var2 = c(4, 3, NA, 2))

df2 = data.frame(time = c(0.04, 0.08, 0.1, 0.12),
             var3 = c(2, 7, 5, 9))
```

How do I merge these two data frames with only one frequency? The time column should look like

```
time = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04)
```

etc.

How do I resample my data so the previous value of the same column is always used? The result looks like this.

```
dfRes  = data.frame(time = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 
                             0.09, 0.1, 0.11, 0.12, 0.13),
             var1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
             var2 = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
             var3 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 7, 7, 5, 5, 9, 9))
```

I think dfRes$var3 shows the idea behind this.

I need this for some plots and machine learning algorithms in the later process.
So I don't know if it makes sense to use a time series format.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "even downscale the time maybe to 100Hz (0.01)"? Could you explain a bit?

Comment: First, I am sorry for changing my question. I didn't see an answer so I changed the question a bit. I edited again for better understanding ;)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `fill`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
     mutate(time = as.numeric(substr(time, 1, 3)) %>%
     fill(var1, var2)
```

Comment: `fill`simplifies a lot, +1! By the way, `round` seems not a good option to achieve OP's expected output, maybe more likely to truncate from the second decimal...

Comment: Yes, sure, it is free for everyone to use :)

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding ii changed it to `substr` to make for diversity. thanks

Comment: this is not working for me :( I got an error "no applicable method for 'fill' ...

Comment: @Bolle have you loaded `tidyr` and also can you check the `packageVersion('tidyr')`

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution

```
inds <- which(is.na(df),arr.ind = TRUE)
df[inds] <- df[cbind(inds[,"row"]-1,inds[,"col"])]
df$time <- floor(10*df$time)/10
```

which gives

```
> df
  time var1 var2
1  0.1    1    4
2  0.2    1    5
3  0.3    4    5
4  0.4    2    3
5  0.5    6    2
6  0.6    6    1
```